# Parse error while declaring const integer in class in php

Tags: php, parsing, integer, constants

I am writing a user class in which I have a few constant variables.

```
class users{
    const integer USER_ACTIVATED = 1;
    const integer USER_BLOCKED = 0;
    const integer USER_SUBSCRIBED = 1;
    const integer USER_UNSUBSCRIBED = 0;

    private $user_id, $user_name, $user_password;

    public function __construct($user_id){
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
}
```

This is a minified test user class. When ever I try to run this file through localhost to debug, it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'USER_ACTIVATED' (T_STRING), expecting '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Users.php on line 2
```

I have gone through many examples to sort out the problem but found nothing.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `integer` isn't a keyword in php ?! just remove it

Comment: @Rizier123 I found const integer declaration in php manual that is why I was applying it. Anyways How do I check whether if it is working fine or not?

Comment: Where did you found this in the manual?

Comment: It may be irrelevant but I was applying reflectionmethods in my class and I found it here
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php

Comment: This is the signature of the class! And not the definition

Comment: So what should I do to access const variables out side the class?

Comment: Normal syntax with `::` like this: `echo users::USER_ACTIVATED;`

Comment: Just read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php <- It's all there and explained with an example. I don't see now what you question is?

Comment: I have corrected my syntax now it gives me the error
unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Did you placed the echo statement in the class definition ?

Comment: But where did you placed the echo function

Comment: I have tried echo statement within class definition and in other class as well but error remains

Comment: Update your question with updated format

Comment: @TeamIncredibles Maybe because it's the class definition ?! You don't place a echo statement in a class definition ! That's PHP OOP 101, please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php Your are defining the class and there is no place for a randomly place echo statement. Only property and method definitions are in a class definition

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for your assistance, I followed your words and it worked for me. I tested it with other class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like **Rizier123** said: `integer` is not a keyword in PHP.
PHP therefore thinks `integer` is the name of your variable and thus expects the equal sign rather than another identifier.

Just leave out `integer` and you should be good to go:

```php
class users
{
    const USER_ACTIVATED = 1;
    const USER_BLOCKED = 0;
    const USER_SUBSCRIBED = 1;
    const USER_UNSUBSCRIBED = 0;

    private $user_id, $user_name, $user_password;

    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think an explanation not only for the OP, but also for further SO visitors would  be helpful.